# How to automatically disconnect and connect to a different wifi network when "no internet"

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, windows-10, router

I have two internet connections & I use with two wifi routers, sometimes one internet connection goes down then how can I automatically connect to my other wifi router(which routing connection from other service provider)

For Windows 10 Laptop.
(with Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter)

Comment: I have no option for "roaming aggressiveness" in wifi adapter properties

Answer (score 0):

Found this on stack

> I was looking to do this myself just now. What you want to do is set the "roaming aggressiveness" of you wifi adapter. You should be able to do this by
>
> going to network and sharing center
> select change adapter settings
> select your wifi adapter and select properties
> click the "configure" button on the popup window (network tab)
> click the advanced tab
> if roaming aggressiveness is there, set it to "highest.
> Your laptop should now seek out the strongest signal.

[image: Adapter Properties > Roaming Aggressiveness Setting > 6. Highest]

In Ralink, there are similar settings just like Intel except Ralink uses the name roaming sensitivity instead of roaming aggressiveness.

Comment: I have no option of "roaming aggressiveness"

Comment: @BlackFire updated my answer, if you don't have intel or Ralink, what brand wireless adapter does your laptop have?

Comment: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter